# Finding Minecraft saves on old hard drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, windows-10

I replaced my old hard drive with a new SSD, and didn't grab my old saves for MineCraft beforehand. The old hard drive is connected back into my computer as a secondary drive (D:) I haven't wiped it yet, so the saves should still be there, right?

I can't find where the saves are - the internet says the file path should be `Users/<user name>/AppData/Roaming` ... etc. When I go into the `<user name>` folder, AppData isn't there.

How do I find the old save files? I'm running the latest version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

AppData is a hidden folder.  You will have to enable hidden items.  In file explorer, click view, then click hidden items check box.  [Here is a tutorial.](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/20/windows-10/show-hidden-files-folders-windows-10.html)

Windows 10, your directory would be:
`D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves`

Change `<username>` to your old user name for windows.

You can then copy the entire contents of the saves folder into the new minecraft saves folder to transfer all of your old worlds.

Comment: Alternative to changing settings: Just append "\Appdata" to the folder path at the top.